# Stream copy not working properly on multi-track video generated by OBS (FFmpeg)

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm simply trying to extract an audio track from a multi-track video generated by OBS using `-c:a copy` to avoid re-encoding, full command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv" `
-map a:2 -c:a copy "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"
```

However, the resulting file is clearly corrupt. It only contains quiet / short segments (basically blips) of what it should, and only plays back for 1/50th its actual duration. I even tried playing the file back using FFplay:

```
ffplay -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"
```

with no luck, heeding the same results. Testing this command on other videos from OBS with one instead of multiple audio tracks, and OBS generated videos with different containers (mp4, flv, etc) all spit out the same garbled files. Using the exact same options / command on an FFmpeg generated video however, and other video files I had on hand, seemed to work just fine. I proceeded to try re-encoding the audio with these options:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv" `
-map a:2 -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 320k "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"
```

and to my surprise got the same results again. I found that the only way to get the newly generated wav files to actually resemble the audio from OBS generated videos I had to use the `pcm_s16le` encoder, example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv" `
-map a:2 -c:a pcm_s16le "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"
```

With these options, the new wav file plays back just like you'd expect. However, now I have to wait for it to re-encode the file, in some cases multiple times depending on the scenario. I've never had stream copy fail me on any other video / audio files I've used it on, anyone know what could be causing this?

Full FFmpeg output:

```
PS C:\Users\gabri> ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv" `
>> -map a:2 -c:a copy "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"                                                ffmpeg version git-2020-01-29-de1b2aa Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.100 / 58. 67.100
  libavformat    58. 36.100 / 58. 36.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 71.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:04:58.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60553 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt709/bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.517000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track1
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track2
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
    Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track3
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
    Stream #0:4: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track4
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
    Stream #0:5: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track5
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
    Stream #0:6: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track6
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
Output #0, wav, to 'C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track3
      DURATION        : 00:04:58.423000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   11658kB time=00:04:58.42 bitrate= 320.0kbits/s speed= 331x
video:0kB audio:11658kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000787%
```

Here are my OBS settings:
https://postimg.cc/gallery/1kahe1o4q/

And lastly here is one of the video files giving me a headache:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10QneHPO_lRMDA0qNFCuyn5S90Eubn8q0

Comment: Can't access your file - permission required.

Comment: I think it was because I was sharing from a G-Suite account, should work now, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAC should be in ADTS framing, but the WAV muxer has no provision to reformat AAC streams, so pipe it through MPEG-TS muxer which does.

`ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Replay 2020-01-26 00-19-35.mkv"
-map a:2 -c:a copy -f mpegts - | ffmpeg -y -f mpegts -i - -c copy "C:\Users\gabri\Videos\OBS Replay Buffer\Test.wav"`

Comment: This would explain why when using the exact same command on my FFmpeg generated videos, which were encoded using the MPEG-TS muxer, worked just fine despite also being aac.

Answer (score 0):

The audio tracks are aac. but are writing to a wav. But you are telling ffmpeg it should not convert from aac to wav via -c:a copy. So it’s impossible for ffmpeg to handle that requirement.

Comment: AAC is acceptable inside WAV. There are five tags listed for it in riff.c